# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).pqSelect is not a function

Tags: jquery

I am using pqSelect for multiple selection. But I cant add the pqSelect initializer inside

```
$(function () {

};
```

. It shows the error Uncaught TypeError: $(...).pqSelect is not a function

```
$(function () {    
     $("#currentloc").pqSelect({
         singlePlaceholder: 'Your current city *',
         checkbox: true //adds checkbox to options    
     }).pqSelect();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed the plugin? As far as I know, .pqSelect requires this plugin here:
http://paramquery.com

Download here: https://github.com/paramquery/select/archive/v1.3.0.zip

Note that paramquery requires both jQuery and jQueryUI to work.

In your HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path to pqgrid.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js">
```

Comment: Now it is working inside jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {   }); 
But I am calling a function to refresh the option list. It is not working. 
$("#currentloc").pqSelect( "refresh" );

Comment: Try $("#currentloc").pqSelect("refreshData");